# Lodash in Angular Template Efficiency

Tags: performance, angular, templates, view, lodash

I have an Angular 2.x app that leverages Lodash in its components, and I'm considering using it in the view templates as well.

I've noticed that Angular (in switching from 1.x to 2.x) dropped support for some of its more intensive view template pipes (like `filter` and `orderBy`) for ["performance reasons,"](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ajs-quick-reference.html#!#filters-pipes) and it now says to "do it in the component."

Should using Lodash in the view follow the same advice?  Is there a "performance reason" why I shouldn't be using Lodash (or comparable libraries) in the view?  Are there times that it doesn't make a difference and times that it does?

Some example usage could be the following:

```html
<div *ngIf="_.isEmpty(someVariable)">
  ....
</div>
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of _.union(arrayOne, arrayTwo)">
  ....
</div>
```

Thanks for any input!  The project in question is open source and hosted [here](https://github.com/umts/pvta-multiplatform).

Comment: angular change detection is the performance issue here. if you are going to call loadash api in the view, why not call it in your component class? its cleaner that way and easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash function or any calculation function on template binding is risky.

Angular change detection will run this function way too many times then you intended and this may cause lags or infinite loops, bind variables instead.

trigger loadash or any calculation on component hooks is much more efficient.